# Featured Image not displaying in a page

Tags: pages, post-thumbnails

I put featured image in a page but it's not showing up when I view the page. But in thumbnails its showing up. How to fix this?

here http://www.homecredit.ph/betasite/promos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `page.php` or `single.php` whichever is concerned here.

After the post title code, add this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Additional modification can be found in [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)